# UIWebView определить открывает ли ссылка новое окно (закладку)

Tags: objective-c, ios

Добрый день!

Как в `UIWebView` перехватить нажатие на ссылку с таргетом для нового окна (`<a target="_blank"`)?

В методе

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

navigationType всегда возвращает `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked` для каждой ссылки.

Comment: напрямую это сделать не получится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На [просторах англоязычного stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19500768/1558147) нашел вот такое решение:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request     navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([request.URL.absoluteString hasPrefix:@"newtab:"])
    {
        // JS-hacked URl is a target=_blank url - manually open the browser.
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[request.URL.absoluteString substringFromIndex:7]];
        // here you can do what your whant
        // [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

        return true;
    }

    return true;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    // JS Injection hack to solve the target="_blank" issue and open a real browser in such case.
    NSString *JSInjection = @"javascript: var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); if (allLinks) {var i;for (i=0; i<allLinks.length; i++) {var link = allLinks[i];var target = link.getAttribute('target'); if (target && target == '_blank') {link.setAttribute('target','_self');link.href = 'newtab:'+link.href;}}}";
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:JSInjection];
}
```

По сути, мы добавляем проткол `newtab:` у всех ссылок, у которых выставлен `target="_blank"` а потом детектим этот протокол при клике.